# I accidentally changed a User folder into a a desktop. Is there a way to restore original user folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, desktop

I was trying to move my user folders to another location.  In doing so, I incorrectly pointed the Desktop to the user folder.  Now the Users folder shows "Desktop" instead of the name of the user folder.

[image: current folder situation]

My desktop now looks like this:
[image: desktop]

I tried to "Restore Default" of the file location, but when I do I get an error, "Can't redirect a parent into a child.  The specified path is invalid."

[image: restore to default]
[image: error message]

Is there a way to recover the user folder and retrieve the original folder locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error was shown because the your user name folder was renamed to `Desktop`. To fix that error, follow these steps:

1. Rename the new Desktop folder to your user name. Let assume user name is `Andrew`. For example, the renaming will be from `C:\Users\Desktop` to `C:\Users\Andrew`.
2. Check if a folder exists as `C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop`. If that folder doesn't exist create a Desktop folder in `C:\Users\Andrew` directory.
3. Then try to 'Restore Default' as usual. See this [article](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/23504-restore-default-location-personal-folders-windows-10-a.html) for further reading.

Answer (score -1):

For example, C:\A\B, we can redirect B into A, but we cannot redirect A into B. 
We can try to redirect the Desktop to another directory(for example D:\"folder name"), then redirect the Desktop into the specified path you want to.