# I Accidently Made My User Folder "Desktop"

Tags: windows-10, desktop

I have the same problem as 'Andrew' had but now on windows 10 ([I accidentally changed a User folder into a a desktop. Is there a way to restore original user folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/1341696/i-accidentally-changed-a-user-folder-into-a-a-desktop-is-there-a-way-to-restore/1341813#1341813?newreg=bf8e4d5aa5ab4ca68c28dc0664599813))

But, I am unable to rename/move the "Desktop"

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you explain in detail how you moved your user's profile exactly?  Andrew never did specify, how they were able to do that, that typically involves many complicated steps in earlier versions of Windows 10.  You should be able to move Desktop, by right clicking the icon, and moving the location.  Are you unable to do that?

Comment: I was trying to move my users folder to my hdd from my ssd, and i accidently draged something into the wrong place and this has happened, thats all i know @Ramhound

Comment: Are you sure you didn't simply drag an icon?  Have you tried my suggestion of right click the desktop and moving it to the new location?  Why were you dragging and dropping the icon, instead of using the feature, to actually move it (and likewise update the registry).  The question you linked to is light on specific details so if you want an answer you will have to provide them.

Comment: im not really sure what i did, but when i look at the properties the desktop IS my user, but it works like a desktop. i have no idea what i have done @Ramhound